# Необходим ли здесь какой-либо знак?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть такая строчка в песне: "Просто прячу свой страх прожить всю жизнь без тебя". Или "Просто прячу свой страх, прожить всю жизнь без тебя"? Или же "Просто прячу свой страх — прожить всю жизнь без тебя". Если необходим какой-либо из этих знаков, то почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть на дилемму формально, то *можно* обойтись без знаков препинания. Однако в этом случае концепция "*страх прожить всю жизнь без тебя*" преподносится собеседнику как нечто само собой разумеющееся или уже сообщавшееся ему. Более вероятно, что ему это сообщают впервые и поэтому хотят преподнести доходчиво, мол у меня есть страх, а заключен он в том-то. Подобное опущенное отступление может компенсироваться при помощи **тире**, которое соответствует интонационной паузе в устной форме.